# How to Load only selective classes or beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classloader

I have an Interface say A, and five implementations for it say A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 in the same package.
Now when starting spring application, I only want to load one say A1 out of A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 depending upon autowiring. I dont want to load others as it will make the application heavy if there are many classes like those.  Please explain possible answer.

Answer (score 2):

**@Qualifier**

Assume you have following context:

```
<bean id="a1_beanId" class="com.A1" >
</bean>

<bean id="a2_beanId" class="com.A2" >
</bean>
```

You have to use [qualifier](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/) to autowire `A` interface with correct realization. Autowiring then happens by `bean id`.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("a1_beanId")
private A yourA1Bean;
```

**@Lazy**

To prevent beans being loaded to spring context you have to switch on [lazy mode](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) using annotation `@Lazy` or `lazy-init="true"` for xml config.

> A lazily-initialized bean indicates to the IoC container whether or
>   not a bean instance should be created at startup or when it is first
>   requested.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but muy question is about stopping the loading of classes which are not getting autowired.

Comment: @Rajdeep, I improved my answer

Comment: If we move to lazy initialization, spring still load all classes, I want to jsut stop that loading of classes.

Comment: Then you have met this case: `if the lazy-initialized bean is the dependency of a singleton bean that is not lazy-initialized, when the ApplicationContext is eagerly pre-instantiating the singleton, it will have to satisfy all of the singletons dependencies, one of which will be the lazy-initialized bean! So don't be confused if the IoC container creates one of the beans that you have explicitly configured as lazy-initialized at startup`

Comment: Its not about bean instanciation, its about loading only selected classes when loading spring application context

Comment: @Rajdeep, I asked question about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694980/spring-is-lazy-initialization-preventing-class-to-be-loaded