# Spring: Is lazy initialization preventing class to be loaded?

Tags: java, spring, classloader

Assume I have:

```
<bean id="a1_beanId" class="com.rudziankou.MyUnusedClass" lazy-init="true" >
</bean>
```

I have never use this bean during app run.

**Questions:**

1. Will `com.rudziankou.MyUnusedClass` be loaded by **Class Loader**?
2. Do we have access to change default spring `class loading` behavior?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/32090706/1793718 & http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Comment: @Lucky, from my understanding `Class Loading` and `instantiation` are different things, aren't they?

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ, yes you're right. Class loading is being handled by the Class loader in Java, and it means making the class available in the JVM.  Instantiation is creating new instance of the class using `new` or `class.forName()`.  From my understanding loading of class in Java happens as soon as another class references it.  Anyways, there a so many experts here and I'm interested for their answers too.